# Trusted Web Activity save data locally

Tags: local-storage, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I have a PWA where I save user settings on local storage and I would like to deploy this PWA on the Play Store through TWA. The problem is the following:

```
The host app doesn't have direct access to web content in a Trusted Web 
activity or any other kind of web state, like cookies and localStorage. 
Nevertheless, you can coordinate with the web content by passing data to and 
from the page in URLs (e.g. through query parameters, custom HTTP headers, and 
intent URIs.)
```

According to what google says, I don't understand how to save the user settings on client side with TWA on a PWA.
If you could show me an example I would be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications that use TWAs are composed from native code (eg: Java or Kotlin) and Web code (HTML, CSS and JavaScript).

The "host app" described in the text is a reference to the native part of the app, which is used to "launch" the web part, the TWA. This native part of the app will not have access to localStorage.

The web part of the app (PWA), will have normal access to localStorage, cookies, etc.

In other words, a PWA that uses localStorage using Trusted Web Activities should behave as expected.

This storage is also shared with Chrome.